# Configure sendmail on RHEL 6.3 to send email using my Microsoft exchange account

Tags: linux, sendmail

I need to send email from RHEL host running 6.3 to my microsoft exchange email ID.
Can any one please help me with detail steps for the configuration.
I am new to Linux so tried some steps from webpages but not succeeded.

I have done the configuration as follows:

1. Edited '/etc/mail/local-host-names' with my Linux server fqdn.
2. Edited '/etc/mail/access' and as below:

> `Connect:mailserver.xxx.com              RELAY`
>    `Connect:mailserver                      RELAY`
>   `Connect:127.0.0.1                       RELAY`

3. makemap hash /etc/mail/access.db < /etc/mail/access
4. Edited `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` as below:

> dnl  DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')

5. m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
6. Service sendmail restart

At this stage all service started ok

```
[root@xxx mail]# service sendmail restart
Shutting down sm-client:                                   [  OK  ]
Shutting down sendmail:                                    [  OK  ]
Starting sendmail:                                         [  OK  ]
Starting sm-client:                                        [  OK  ]
```

Now I tried to send email:

```
mail -s "Test Email"  syed@xxx.com < /dev/null
Mail sent successfully but not delivered to mail ID.

[root@xxxx mail]# mailq
/var/spool/mqueue is empty
                Total requests: 0
```

But I am not able to receive any email. In  /var/spool/mail/root it shows its sending mail but not able to deliever. Will keep trying for 5 days before giving up.

Appreciate any support to fix this issue.

Comment: What exactly do you need? Simply configure sendmail such that messages from your server to `syed@example.com` get delivered? Or should all outgoing message, to any address, get redirected so that messages  such as to `bob@ServerFault`  and   to `alice@example.gov.uk`  end up in your mailbox on the Exchange server? Or should the exchange server be used as the outgoing smtp server, the smarthost in jargon?

Comment: Yes, I need to simply configure sendmail to send messages from my server to my email id syed@example.com Also need to send email from an automated script of OracleDB to few users. HBruijn

Comment: Typically `/var/log/maillog` will give some hints on why the message is rejected.

Comment: [root@xxxxxx~]# echo hello |sendmail -v Syed@xxx.com

xxx.com: Name server timeout

Syed@xxxx.com... Transient parse error -- message queued for future delivery

Syed@xxxx.com.. queued


HBruijn

Comment: The hint is: `Name server timeout`  - That indicates that the resolver you've configured isn't responding, check the settings you used in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Able to send email from sendmail command but not recieving in my mailbox...
Getting below error in /var/spool/mail/root after sending mail
----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<Syed@xxx.net>

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
550 5.1.2 <Syed@xxx.net>... Host unknown (Name server: xxx.net: host not found) HBrujin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[root@xxx ~]# nslookup -type=mx xxx.net

Server:         xx.xxx.xx.10
Address:        xx.xxx.xx.10#53

*** Can't find xxxx.net: No answer

****Sendmail didn't worked for me... atlast I sent email using postfix:****

PostFix:

Edit /etc/postfix/main.cf

Below the relayhost examples, add this line:

relayhost = smtp.xxx.com

Restart postfix:

/etc/init.d/postfix restart
Sendmail:

Edit /etc/mail/sendmail.mc

Change: 
dnl #(`SMART_HOST',`localhost')dnl

To: 
(`SMART_HOST',`smtp.xxx.com')dnl

Save the file, and from the /etc/mail directory run "sudo make"

Restart sendmail
/etc/init.d/sendmail restart

## sendmail -v Syed@xxx.com

Mail working and recieved

Answer (score 0):

From your latest comment:

> The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----  ----- Transcript of session follows ----- 550 5.1.2 ... **Host unknown** (**Name server: xxx.net**: host not found)

Seems a clear indication of what's wrong. You have resolving problems.

Either your name servers are not configured correctly. Check your /etc/resolv.conf and from the commandline with for instance with `nslookup -type=mx example.com`

```
# Sample /etc/resolv.conf using Google's public DNS
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Alternatively the name-servers you are using are not capable of resolving your domain, for instance because they are not recursive..